# tabulator filter: ungroup filter results

Tags: filter, grouping, tabulator

in my tabulator table I group specific rows. When I load the page I keep the groupings closed, so that the user can open those grouping he is interested in. (see attached screenshot)
But I would like to automatically open the groupings, when the user applies a filter to any column of the table. (because in this case I want him to see the results on first glance and I do not want him to open the grouping manually) Do you know how I can set up this specific requirement?

[Open grouping when applying a column filter in tabulator js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMIPo.png)

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

To check when the table is filtered you can use the ***dataFiltered*** callback, you would need to check through the filters passed into the callback to make sure that there are filters actually applied before carrying out your app logic.

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    dataFiltered:function(filters, rows){
    //filters - array of filters currently applied
    //rows - array of row components that pass the filters
    },
});
```

You could the use the ***getGroups*** function to return an array of the [Group Components](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/components#component-group) for the table, and the itterate through the list and open the groups using the ***show*** function:

```js
table.getGroups().forEach(function(group){
    group.show();
});
```

I hope that helps,

Cheers

Oli :)

Comment: Would be useful if you could write how to compose the 2 parts to achieve what is required by OP.